# Динамическое подключение к базам данных

Tags: yii2

Существует основное подключение к базе данных **project_database**. Но помимо него существует еще **n**-количество баз данных, для некоторых пользователей системы. Параметры подключения к пользовательским базам, хранятся в основной базе в таблице пользователей. Необходимо подключится к пользовательской базе данных **project_database_client_123** и выполнить запрос.

Нужно создавать для каждого подключения компонент? И потом переопределять метод **getDb** у **Application**, для переключения между ними. Или есть какой-то более изящный способ?

```
class Connection extends \yii\db\Connection {

    /**
     * @var \yii\db\Connection[] $connections
     */
    private $connections = [];

    public function getClientConnection($clientID) {
        if (!isset($this->connections[$clientID])) {
            if (!$client = Client::findOne($clientID)) {
                throw new Exception('Client not found');
            }

            $connection = new \yii\db\Connection([
                'dsn' => "{$this->dsn}_client_{$clientID}",
                'username' => $client->db_user,
                'password' => $client->db_password,
            ]);
            $connection->open();

            $this->connections[$clientID] = $connection;
        }

        return $this->connections[$clientID];
    }

    public function closeClientConnection($clientID) {
        if (isset($this->connections[$clientID])) {
            $this->connections[$clientID]->close();
            unset($this->connections[$clientID]);
        }
    }
}
```

Ну и использование где-то такое.

```
$results = Yii::$app->db
        ->getClientConnection($account->client_id)
        ->createCommand($query, [
            ':accountID' => $accountID,
        ])
        ->queryAll();
```

P.S. Это именно разные базы данных, а не схемы одной базы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы используете ActiveRecord, и для выбора базы берёте сведения о текущем авторизованном пользователе, то удобно и вполне изящно будет переопределить `getDb` не в `Application` а конкретно в тех классах AR, таблицы которых "шардятся" по разным базам.

Например, как-то так (для шаблона basic):

*components/DbConnectionManager.php*

```
class DbConnectionManager extends Component
{
    public function getClientConnection($clientID)
    {
        // your code here
    }

    public function getCurrentClientConnection()
    {
        retrun $this->getClientConnection(\Yii::$app->user->id);
    }
}
```

*config/web.php*

```
'components' => [
    'dbConnectionManager' => [
        'class' => 'app/components/DbConnectionManager'
    ]
]
```

*models/SomeUserData.php*

```
class SomeUserData extends ActiveRecord 
{
    public static function getDb()
    {
        return \Yii::$app->dbConnectionManager->getCurrentClientConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: В целом решение с переопределением **getDb** для модели интересное. Спасибо, возьму на заметку. Но увы это как раз тот случай когда ActiveRecord не используется. Да и конкретно в этой ситуации. Получается что сама модель Client и её связи относится к основной базе, а детальные данные по клиентам хранятся в шардах, и одна модель будет работать одновременно с несколькими подключениями. Пока что остановился на решение с расширением базового компонента

Comment: @Ninazu понятно. Но если говорить о "изящности" то я бы тогда рекомендовал аккуратно изолировать логику шардинга в отдельном классе. Например, так `ClientConnection extends \yii\db\Connection` и `(new ClientConnection($client))->createCommand ...`. Ну или как-то еще. В любом случае, то как у вас написано (Connection порождает Connection, который семантически не связан с родителем + процедурный подход для открытия/закрытия) это не очень хорошо -- не прозрачно, будет плохо поддаваться модульному тестированию, и т.д.... источник ошибок в общем. см. "принципы SOLID".